# How create static model in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

For example, I get response from server with regular object:

```
obj = {count: 1, returned : 1}
```

I need to save this object in data model and after transfer this in the next requests to server.

So, it should be model, that I can get in any class in Laravel.
How I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a model with `count` and `returned` and those are the only required fields you can just pass an array version of the object into the [create](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models) method:

```
$obj = {count: 1, returned : 1};
$model = SampleModel::create((array) $obj);
```

You will also need to put in your model `fillable` attributes:

```
class SampleModel extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['count', 'returned'];
}
```

Comment: This is not that I assumed. I need mechanism like as in Objective C with `property`, when based on this I create static model.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your question. Do you want some sort of object that persists between requests outside of the database?